# SSIS integrated with SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, excel, oracle, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS job with SQL Agent job (Management Studio 2016). The SSIS job is as follows Source: Oracle to Destination: Excel file on another a shared folder(network). Without setting up a proxy ( it failed on me several times) I am getting this message.

1: Config file is also attached to the Job

Thanks

"Message
Executed as user: OMH\Istcrmt. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:43:17 PM  Error: 2016-12-01 12:43:18.35     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Package Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "'S:\Shared\SFD\DAT Reporting\Rich Test.xls' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".  End Error  Error: 2016-12-01 12:43:18.35     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task Excel Destination [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2016-12-01 12:43:18.35     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Excel Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2016-12-01 12:43:18.35     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2016-12-01 12:43:18.35     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:43:17 PM  Finished: 12:43:18 PM  Elapsed:  0.594 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed."

Comment: Try using UNC rather than a mapped drive.

Comment: make sure your SQL Agent and/or SQL Service account have permissions to the file, and the path will need to be relative to the SQL server.  so if s drive is not local to the sql server you will need unc path.  In that case too the sql agent and sql service accounts would have to be domain accounts so you can assign permissions otherwise you will need a proxy domain account.

Comment: IS there an issue with the excel connection manager I am overseeing? I just modified the Config file to include the oracle connection password

Comment: @Tinkinc, your error dump says nothing about Oracle. All errors are related to Excel connection manager.

Comment: And how do I remedy that?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of your error code,anyone can guess the error.
Actually you have not set the file path correctly in `connection Manager`.
Please set the path in Connection Manager with your **server Name**(Network Location path), please check below path for your reference:

> `"\\10.160.25.255\S$\Shared\SFD\DAT Reporting\Rich Test.xlsx"`

You can used Server IP (10.160.25.255 for example) or host name (WKWIN9628520) instead of IP , then definitely this error won't come again.